# Trying to render a .mov file in Blender's video editor

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to render a small clip from a huge video I recorded via a screen recorder. However, I can only render it as an AVI file. Is there a way to output in other formats? What I'm doing is choosing the H.264 codec but no luck. Specifically, I am trying to render it as an MOV file.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to set the encoding settings correct.

The following settings will output a .mov file with h.264 codec.

[image: encoding settings for mov h.264]

Comment: Thanks for responding! Just another question... if I have audio in my video, do I still have to do the Audio Codec as None for it to render as a .mov file?

EDIT: Nevermind, tried it out for myself and it seems fine. Thanks for the help!